# huge difference by count API between primary and replica shards in elasticsearch

Tags: count, elasticsearch

I'm currently bulk indexing massive data into elasticsearch (Actually there are a lot data inside the index originally, and I updated the mapping and started loading again.).

The URL I used is an ELB provided by Amazon.

However, when I count the # of doc, I found in the primary shard(using preference=primary_first), there is nothing, while there are actually over 10m data inside the index(no preference=primary_first).

I'm wondering why this happened and how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I should use preference=_primary_first. Then it is the # of docs in primary shard.

But it still puzzles me that for some other shards(also being indexed), there is no such problem, while for some specific shards, there are. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you use routing for those indices: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html